# Synchronizing singleton in Java

Tags: java, android

I have just encountered code where synchronization was done on wrong class:

```
public class Test
{
    public static volatile Test instance = null;

    public static void setIfNull(Test newInstance)
    {
        synchronized (WRONG.class) // should be synchronized (Test.class)
        {
            if (newInstance == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("newInstance must not be null.");
            if (instance == null) instance = newInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

Above error would not happen if whole method was synchronized:

```
public class Test
{
    public static volatile Test instance = null;

    public static synchronized void setIfNull(Test newInstance)
    {
        if (newInstance == null) 
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("newInstance must not be null.");
        if (instance == null) instance = newInstance;
    }
}
```

The way I see it, second piece of code is more error proof than first one.

Are there any pitfalls of using method synchronization over synchronization block concerning above code pattern?

---

*Warning:* In above code `instance` field is not properly encapsulated. Being public member nothing prevents external code not only to read it, but also write to it in thread unsafe manner. This code should not be used as proper thread safe singleton example because that is not what it is.

Comment: The second block is less error prone as you don't need to specify the class objects as it is implied.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, those are my thoughts, exactly. Any other differences I should be aware of?

Comment: The byte code is actually different, however these difference rarely matter.

Comment: @Tomas it is not a duplicate of that question because my question is about static class members. Also, I am asking about very specific use case where I know that both ways do the same thing, I just want to be 100% sure that I am not missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any pitfalls of using method synchronization over synchronization block concerning above code pattern?

Since this:

```
public static synchronized void setIfNull(Test newInstance) {
    ...
}
```

...is exactly the same ([JLS 8.4.3.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6)) as this:

```
public static void setIfNull(Test newInstance) {
    synchronized (Test.class) {
        ...
    }
}
```

...what you are really asking is: "What is the difference between synchronizing on some other class object `WRONG.class` and on `This.class`?".

The only thing to look out for is whether something else in your code decides to synchronize on `Test.class`.

Comment: There are however many other pitfalls in your code, but those are not what you ask about so I won't go into them.

Comment: I know there are other pitfalls in my code :) That is why I have added warning to the question, so that less knowledgeable devs would not grab that code and use it without knowing there are huge pitfalls involved.

Answer (score -1):

1) One significant difference between synchronized method and block is that, Synchronized block generally reduce scope of lock. As scope of lock is inversely proportional to performance, its always better to lock only critical section of code. One of the best example of using synchronized block is double checked locking in Singleton pattern where instead of locking whole getInstance() method we only lock critical section of code which is used to create Singleton instance. This improves performance drastically because locking is only required one or two times.

2) Synchronized block provide granular control over lock, as you can use arbitrary any lock to provide mutual exclusion to critical section code. On the other hand synchronized method always lock either on current object represented by this keyword  or class level lock, if its static synchronized method.

3) Synchronized block can throw throw java.lang.NullPointerException if expression provided to block as parameter evaluates to null, which is not the case with synchronized methods.

4) In case of synchronized method, lock is acquired by thread when it enter method and released when it leaves method, either normally or by throwing Exception. On the other hand in case of synchronized block, thread acquires lock when they enter synchronized block and release when they leave synchronized block.

Read more: http://java67.blogspot.com/2013/01/difference-between-synchronized-block-vs-method-java-example.html#ixzz3qAc5gOJy

Comment: That answer has does not provide answer to the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

I cant remember any pitfalls when you synchronize whole methods. Of course those are more "expensive" that just locks around certain areas.

If you're not sure i would always go for the synchronized method first until you encounter is as a bottleneck.

To avoid blocking on the wrong object simple create an instance variable:

```
private final Object block = new Object();
```

And use this when you need sychronization. Anyway when you do so, keep in mind that other methods called by different threads dont respect this and you get side effects. So you have to be careful when going this way. 
I read quite some books on those topics thats an really concrete answer ist hard to mark as the correct one.

I recommend that you read "Java Concurrency in Practice" from Brian Goetz.

Also "Java Core" from Angelika Langer, Klaus Kreft (a book that goes into deep when it comes to using the volatile keyword) (German Book, still curious that no one translated this into english as it is a masterpiece in its area).

Also you could use reentant locks to get fair locking if you like.

Comment: I am not locking on object, but on class, since this is static instance.

Comment: well, why you not simply lock the whole static class then ? When i remeber static classes are complete locked by the thread it owns.

Comment: "static classes are complete locked by the thread it owns" - this sentence makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but your answer does not address my question at all. The only part that is somehow related to my Q is in first sentence. But I only asked the question because I wasn't 100% sure that I am not missing something. Having answer that basically states "I am not sure either" is not really helping me.

Comment: Ever through that you question may not precise ?

Comment: My question was precise. There are static member and static method in code that is quite short and easy to understand. I also noted that I think that second piece of code is better than first one, and my question was "Are there any pitfalls of using method synchronization (2) over synchronization block (1) concerning above code pattern?" I think that is precise enough. I was asking about very specific piece of code.